# Can I parse Javascript inside HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I have being trying to parse a HTML file using the following code below, I have a html file passed into the core.Element.parse, which is then rendered to the view:

```
this.newElement = core.Element.parse(html);
this.view.getContent().append(this.newElement);
```

html file looks like:

```
<div>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4333, -7.9500),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
</div>
```

Can someone tell me why the html, and css gets parsed but the javascript doesnt? When I inspect element the html is there and css but there is no sign of the javascript and nothing appears.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please explain where `core.Element.parse()` comes from. Is it from some library?

Comment: It's guess it is because your library is a DOM parser and not a full on web browser with a JavaScript engine.

Comment: Parses a HTML String and creates an Element from it.

Parameters:

html: String
Returns:
element

: Element
   var element = core.Element.parse("<div></div>");

Comment: Is there away of doing it Quentin without having full javascript engine?

Comment: @Drumalee15 — Reverse engineer the JavaScript and rewrite it in whatever programming language you are working in.

Comment: Reverse engineer? hmm how would that work... sorry im not very clear what you mean.

Comment: Try putting the content of the `<script>` inside `<!-- .. -->` comment markers. If that doesn't work, put it inside a .js file and link to that.

Comment: Mr Lister thanks for your comment I have tried the separate .js file will try the comment thing now.